# wordpress js mobile redirection script only if fronpage not working

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I've created a mobile redirection js file using [these excellent instructions](https://pagecrafter.com/redirect-to-mobile-website-tutorial/) (even though I'm still unsure how to redirect my SSL protected site to a non-protected mobile site without getting rid of the https:// prefix...).
However, this is not the issue at hand.

I'm getting no joy when trying to restrict this mobile redirection script, so it will only work for the **front-page**.
I.e. http://example.com -> http://m.example.com
but a single page such as http://example.com/contact/ (which uses the same header.php template),  will remain the same also for mobile too.

This is how I added the script to the header.php, but as stated before, it's not doing the job:

```
if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://piccolo.co.il/js/redirection-mobile.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
 SA.redirection_mobile ({
 mobile_url : "m.piccolo.co.il",
 });

// ]]></script>';}
</head>
```

currently **every page gets redirected to the mobile version's homepage**, and the if `is_front_page` is being ignored.
My website is http://piccolo.co.il if anyone would like to inspect the code.

Many thanks!
Jon

Comment: Try to add it to wp_enqueue_scripts to load it at the correct moment + validate with var_dump or debugger the actual values of the bools at the time you would expect it to make it transparent + check if either one is true depending on your settings.

Comment: Any idea how to do that? I mean, I know how to add the script to the wp_enqueue_scripts (although I am not sure why it is preferred?) but I don't know how to validate it... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by getting rid of the 'echo' and implementing this code (still in the header, as I didn't quite understand the above reply).
I was advised to use only is_front_page, given the fact that is_home can work a bit awkwardly at times.

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
<?php if ( is_front_page()  ) { ?><script type="text/javascript" src="http://piccolo.co.il/js/redirection-mobile.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
 SA.redirection_mobile ({
 mobile_url : "m.piccolo.co.il",
 });

// ]]></script>';}<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Incidentally - the issue to redirect HTTPS to HTTP can be solved by adding this to the code:  mobile_prefix: "http",